# The pdfscreen's overlay command makes magin error with texlive 2021

Tags: beamer, backgrounds, updating

However beamer class is the best class for presentations, pdfscreen package exports slide quick from a LaTeX file. The background image with overlay command has been perfect before. When the Texlive is update in 2021 the overlay make error with top align.
Please explain why it is? How does I correct this problem.
Many thanks!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[screen,nopanel]{pdfscreen}
\margins{.5in}{.5in}{.5in}{.5in}
\screensize{6.25in}{8in}
\bottombuttons
\notesname{Notes:}
\begin{document}

\overlay{overlay\theslideoverlay}

\begin{slide}\Huge\color{orange}\centering
This is  Slide No. \theslide.\\
\color{blue}\large Slide overlay No. \theslideoverlay.\\
\color{red} Overlay file: \makeatletter\@overlay\makeatother
\end{slide}

\begin{slide}\Huge\color{orange}\centering
This is  Slide No. \theslide.\\
\color{blue}\large Slide overlay No. \theslideoverlay.\\
\color{red} Overlay file: \makeatletter\@overlay\makeatother
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

Comment: notify the author. They use box255 and this should be reviewed to make it compatible  with the shipout of latex.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer. Thank you!

Comment: @Nam Tran Le were you able to get a fix of this?

Comment: @VivekSharma I have not fixed this sir!

Comment: I did write to the author of the package CVR but have not heard from him or his team, quite likely this was written a long time back and he has no time to continue supporting this.

Comment: @VivekSharma Yes sir. Thank you for your information!

Answer (score 2):

I got an answer from David Carlisle at another forum 9https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/616167/40951):  add the following to the first line of the latex preamble. Hope this helps someone else:

\RequirePackage[2019/01/01]{latexrelease}

Comment: Thank you very much. This package conflicts with other command packages.
Do you meet this trouble.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? can you give details?

Comment: When we write \RequirePackage[2019/01/01]{latexrelease} other packages shout out. For example, the exerquiz package gives error ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> You 
               have missed too many questions. After you finish, it is recom...
l.4351 ...fewer errors and greater understanding.}

Comment: Adding to my previous comment: 
When we press x to quit the console, the error tracking opens exerquiz.sty and highlights 

\flJSStr{\sqStrongMsg}{You have missed too many questions.
We are resetting the quiz. Start over, this time with
fewer errors and greater understanding.}