# How to make box255 compatible with the shipout of latex with 2021 update

Tags: shipout, pdfscreen

I have used pdfscreen to make quick slides from a latex document for easy screen readability. However with the latex update in 2021 the overlay feature is erroneous.
I am given to believe that it is due to a problem with box255 and shipout of latex. pdfscreen uses box 255.
I had written to the author of the program but have not heard from him.
Any pointers to the solution will be helpful.

Here is the file I am using.

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[screen,nopanel]{pdfscreen}
\margins{.5in}{.5in}{.5in}{.5in}
\screensize{6.25in}{8in}
\bottombuttons
\notesname{Notes:}
\begin{document}

\overlay{overlay\theslideoverlay}

\begin{slide}\Huge\color{orange}\centering
This is  Slide No. \theslide.\\
\color{blue}\large Slide overlay No. \theslideoverlay.\\
\color{red} Overlay file: \makeatletter\@overlay\makeatother
\end{slide}

\begin{slide}\Huge\color{orange}\centering
This is  Slide No. \theslide.\\
\color{blue}\large Slide overlay No. \theslideoverlay.\\
\color{red} Overlay file: \makeatletter\@overlay\makeatother
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just FYI for those looking at it, you need to go back to something like TL19 to see what this is suppose to look like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest quick fix is to add

```
\RequirePackage[2019/01/01]{latexrelease}
```

as the first line of your document so the format rolls back to a compatible state.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Comment: in the LaTex preamble