# Pdfscreen issue

Tags: pdfscreen

Trying to use the pdfscreen package and not getting desired output.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace,colortbl}
\usepackage[screen,rightpanel,sectionbreak,gray]{pdfscreen}
\begin{screen}
% \overlay{overlay1.pdf}
\margins{.5in}{.5in}{.5in}{.5in}
\screensize{6.25in}{8in}
\end{screen}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{\Large Sample title}

\begin{document}


\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

But the navigation pane has a huge white space that I am not able to remove. [image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: pdfscreen manipulates \shipout and the shipout box in a low-level way. That is not compatible with the new LaTeX shipout hooks. I would recommend not to use that package which hasn't been updated since more than 20 years, as it doesn't look as if the author has the time or the will to adapt it. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/609085/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, not that I disagree with you on the matter, but it seems that the problem can be fixed by replacing the `y` coordinate in the `picture` environment in four places in the `.sty` file. The solution that I proposed also fix the problem in the post that you linked. Maybe the problem isn't that serious? (of course, without maintenance it will get worse...)

Comment: @UdiFogiel try for example \pagecolor{red}. In 2019 this gives a red page. While it is ok to find some work around for an existing document, do you really think one should encourage new users? Or are you willing to take over maintainance?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I was just curious how bad is the incompatibility, as the post you provided, and a couple more that I've found were all about the specific problem described here, and your well informed answer had satisfied my curiosity... thank you :).

Comment: @UdiFogiel I do not really know "how bad" it is. But I put quite some value on maintainance and future compability. Lots of half broken packages in use makes it hard to improve LaTeX.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Is there a list of such packages? maybe I'll find something I can contribute to

Comment: @UdiFogiel I don't know of a list. Perhaps ctan can tell you unmaintained packages. To my mind springs crop (which has a maintainer but doesn't react), cleveref (ditto) and marginnote.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick fix using the `regexpatch` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace,colortbl}
\usepackage[screen,rightpanel,sectionbreak,gray]{pdfscreen}
\begin{screen}
    % \overlay{overlay1.pdf}
    \margins{.5in}{.5in}{.5in}{.5in}
    \screensize{6.25in}{8in}
\end{screen}

\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*\@Overlay@Hook{\put(\strip@pt\@tempdima,\strip@pt\@tempdima)}
{\put(\strip@pt\@tempdima,\strip@pt\dimexpr.5\paperheight)}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{\Large Sample title}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \blinddocument
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I recommend not to use the package.

`pdfscreen` manipulates `\shipout` and the shipout box in a low-level way:

```
\newcommand*{\@PDFSout@Init}{%
   \let\@PDFSout@Org@Out\shipout
   \let\shipout\@PDFSout@Out %<--------- changes \shipout primitive
   }
```

```
      \global\setbox\@cclv\vbox{% <----- @cclv is the shipout box
      ....
      \global\setbox\@cclv= %
```

That is not compatible with the new LaTeX shipout hooks introduced in 2020 (see ltshipout-doc.pdf) and can fail in various way, see e.g. [The pdfscreen's overlay command makes magin error with texlive 2021](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/609085/2388) for another example.

The package has been updated last time in 2000. The author has been notified more than once that it is failing, but it doesn't look as if there will be an update.

Rolling back to an older LaTeX as suggested in the other question is not a long term solution. While LaTeX can roll back, packages typically don't offer this option. If they rely on the new hook system they will fail as code in the hooks are ignored when rolling back.