# Match the text position using pdfscreen's overlay

Tags: pdftex, pdfscreen

I have a `demo.pdf` converted from `demo.doc` as follows (sorry for pdf is not permitted in stack):

[image]

I want to screen some text in latex onto the `demo.pdf` (within the `blablabla:` area) , and I tried:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[screen]{pdfscreen}
\margins{44mm}{11mm}{29mm}{40mm} %\margins{left}{right}{top}{bottom}; before\screensize
\screensize{270mm}{188mm} %\screensize{height}{width}
\overlay{demo.pdf}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

However, the position is not matched!

[image]

How can control the text position (e.g., lifting up and down) to remedy this?

Comment: What is weird is that this same tex file works about one year ago!  Since this `pdfscreen.sty` is a little bit old, I am not sure whether some updated packages related to `\usepackage[screen]{pdfscreen}`  cause the above issue.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675174/pdfscreen-issue#comment1677308_675174

Comment: @ulrike-fischer Thank you for your clue! I use the `regexpatch` package solution therein for temporarily solve my issue.  @ulrike-fischer